# Monty Hall and conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, monty-hall

I am a bit confused. I thought after Monty opens the door with the goat, conditional probabilities kick in and our sample space shrinks down to 2 doors instead of 3, and since they were all equally likely, the two doors now have probabilities of 1/2. But apparently, we are not supposed to use conditional probability here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we are supposed to do conditional probabilities but the doors are **not** equally likely because the door that was opened *did not have the prize* and also the door that was open was not the initially chosen.

The easiest way to see this is consider two strategies: S) always switch the door and N) never switch the door.

If you choose $S$ then you lose only if your original door had the prize, so you win $\frac{2}{3}$ of the time.

If you choose $N$ you only win $\frac{1}{3}$ of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Because you chose a door before Monty opened one means that he did not have an equal probability to chose either unopened door. If he opened a door before you chose, then you would have a 50% chance.

Consider this problem:

Your neighbor has 2 children. You learn that he has a son, Joe. What is the probability that Joe’s sibling is a brother?

The possible children the neigher has is $\{BB, BG, GB, GG\}$. Since you know he has a son, this is reduced to $\{BB, BG, GB\}$.